# jQuery Toggle Div Horizontally Hide Text completley unti toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I would like to create a div that is hidden below another div until it is toggled horizontally via button. The hidden div should contain text that is also hidden but will show also when div is toggled.

This example shows how it should look like. However when I add some text to one of the divs, the text shows. I want it show up only if function is executed and the whole div is toggled:

```
<style>
.map {height: 100px; width: 300px; position: absolute; background:green;}
.t1  {height: 100px; width: 0; position: absolute; background:red;}
.t2  {height: 100px; width: 0; position: absolute; background:blue;}
</style>


<html>
<div id="test">Map Details</div>
<div id="test2">Map Details 2</div>
<div id="close">Close</div>


<div class="map">Im a map</div>


<div class="t1 common"></div>

<div class="t2 common"></div>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible=true;
    $("#test").on('click', function() { 
        $('.t1').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
         visible=!visible;  }); 
     $("#test2").on('click', function() { 
        $('.t2').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
         visible=!visible;         
    });
    $("#close").on('click', function() { 
        $('.common').animate({width: visible ? 0: 0}, "slow");
         visible=!visible;         
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback parameter for animate which executes after animated and toggle the text by wrapping it in span

```
function f1(){
    if (visible)$('span').show();
    else $('span').hide();
}
//...
$('.t1').animate(
   {width: visible ? 300 : 0},
   "slow",f1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aLz6qh7t/7/